# How to retrieve tweets from all cities using Twint package in python?

Tags: python, jupyter

Using Twint, I'm able to get tweets from each city in the list, but while creating a dataframe I only get tweet from the last city in the list, is it possible to append the tweets based on cities?

```
india = ["chennai","pune","mumbai"]
for city in india:
    print(city)
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Search = "phone"
    c.Lang= "en"
    c.Pandas = True
    c.Since = "2021-01-01"
    c.Near = city
    c.Limit = 10
    twint.run.Search(c)
data = twint.output.panda.Tweets_df(["date","tweet","near"])
data.head()

        date                              tweet                              near
0   2021-03-23 18:47:09 Cameron FaulknerThe Black Shark 4 is a high-en...   mumbai
1   2021-03-23 18:42:21 Asad just break Zoya's phone so she won't expo...   mumbai
2   2021-03-23 18:40:13 @Babi3Kat Send you phone number an                  mumbai
3   2021-03-23 18:34:12 @sahilbaani @SamsungIndia ????? 5 Saal purane ...   mumbai
4   2021-03-23 18:33:52 @91mobiles They are just started to make more ...   mumbai
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only seeing the last one since you overwrite your object `df` at each iteration and when the loop is finished it will store only the last value store which happens to be `mumbai`

If you want to create a DataFrame with all the results you should do something like this:

```
ldf = list()
india = ["chennai","pune","mumbai"]
for city in india:
    print(city)
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Search = "phone"
    c.Lang= "en"
    c.Pandas = True
    c.Since = "2021-01-01"
    c.Near = city
    c.Limit = 10
    twint.run.Search(c)
    tmp = twint.output.panda.Tweets_df(["date","tweet","near"])
    ldf.append(tmp)
data = pd.concat(ldf, ignore_index = True)
data.head()
```